# change document _id from object to string?

Tags: mongodb, modulus.io

Currently using this, but doesn't seem to be loading. Does this just take a while or am I doing something wrong? My db is on modulus which is 3.0.3 while my shell is 3.2.1

```
db.itemtemplates.find().snapshot().forEach(
  function (e) {
    // update document, using its own properties
    e._id = e._id.str
    db.itemtemplates.save(e);
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct method to convert an `ObjectId` to string is `toString()`, see the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/).

```
db.itemtemplates.find().snapshot().forEach(
  function (e) {
    // update document, using its own properties
    e._id = e._id.toString()
    db.itemtemplates.save(e);
  }
)
```